# How to add incremental rows in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table as follows:

```
ID  Start End
AB  001   020
VG  004   098
```

I want to output a single row of ID series as follows:

```
ID2
AB001
AB002
AB003
...
AB020
VG001
...
VG097
VG098
```

I am trying to do this with Power Query in Excel as I cannot use R (the tool will be used by another person without access to R).

I am trying Table.InsertRows and Table.RepeatRows after transposing the table. But I am so far unable to use the Start/End values in my query (the number of IDs may vary) or even incrementing the values. I am quite a noob in this and to this day have worked with only minor manipulations of the GUI functions. Any detailed answer will be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your efforts in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it generates a list from Start - End for each row, applies the ID prefix, then combines the output:

```
let
    ListFunction = (Start, End, Prefix) =>
        let
            NewList = List.Transform(List.Numbers(Start, End - Start + 1), each Prefix & Number.ToText(_, "000"))
        in
            NewList,
    Source = #table(type table [#"ID"=text, #"Start"=text, #"End"=text],{{"AB","001","020"},{"VG","004","098"}}),
    #"Make Lists" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "NewList", each ListFunction(Number.From([Start]), Number.From([End]), [ID])),
    #"Combine Lists" = Table.FromList(List.Combine(#"Make Lists"[NewList]), Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"ID2"})
in
    #"Combine Lists"
```

Comment: That worked incredibly well. Thanks a lot. This was easy to understand too.